# PlotProjects - using dwelling notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, geolocation, geofencing

I'm using Plot Projects service to send geofencing notifications to users of iOS and Android application.

I want to use "dwelling" event to trigger specific notifications when user remains at one specific geofence for some extended time. The [documentation](https://www.plotprojects.com/documentation/#iOS_Filter) states that dwelling event can be used on iOS, but has certain specifics:

> Please note that due to restrictions in iOS the notification filter for dwelling notifications is called when the user enters the geofence or beacon region and that the returned notifications are only shown when the user remains in the region for the specified amount of time.

By my understanding, this would mean that the Notification filter gets triggered as soon as user enters the geofence, but the notification, if properly filtered, will be displayed after user dwells there. Filtering logic in my case is done on server-side - iOS app sends notification info to server, and then appropriate logic is applied to decide whether to show notification or not.

So, server-side logic for checking whether to show notification or not would be triggered at the time user trips geofence, but the notification would be shown to the user once he dwells there for some time. In my specific case, in order to properly decide whether to show the notification or not, I'd need the check to be done at the time the user really dwells, and not on entering. My understanding is that this cannot be done on iOS (unlike Android).

Am I right to assume this? If not, what would be the way to achieve a dwell-time filtering check, as opposed to enter-time filtering check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the moment when the Notification Filter will trigger on iOS. This is done because of platform limitations. The filter will be called directly when you enter the geofence. When you want filter out messages, that is indeed the time to do so. There is no way to filter at the time of the end of the dwelling period.

This, as mentioned, differs from the behaviour on Android. There it will be called at the end of the dwelling period.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any other mechanism that I could use here for iOS? How about Geotrigger - can it trigger exactly at dwell time? In such scenario, I could do a check in dwell time and send "standard" push notification from server side.